# Angularjs and laravel file upload on form submission

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, laravel-4

I am a newbie to angularjs and I want to create a form with a file. How can I get the file on angularjs controller and pass it to the laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) is very easy to configure and use and there are some examples for the server side code (also PHP).

If you are using bower, install runnig:

```
bower install ng-file-upload --save
```

and add the `ngFileUpload` to your module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  // other dependencies here
  'ngFileUpload'
]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button" ngf-select ngf-change="upload($files)">Upload on file change</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'upload/url', // change this with the url/route of your laravel action
                fields: {'username': $scope.username}, // this is an example to pass additional fields to pass in the post
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
                alert('file uploaded!');
            });
        }
    }
};
```

See the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t50b3fw/)